# weird NaN when raising a number to a non-integer power

Tags: r, nan

I executed the following code:

```
tau <- 0.25
h <- 0.6 * n ^ (-1 / 5) * (4.5 * dnorm(qnorm(tau)) ^ 4 * qnorm(tau) / 
 (2 * (qnorm(tau) ^ 2 + 1)) ^ 2) ^ (1/5),
```

and R keeps producing `NaN`. However, R actually computes `(4.5 * dnorm(qnorm(tau)) ^ 4 * qnorm(tau) / (2 * (qnorm(tau) ^ 2 + 1)) ^ 2)` to be equal to `-0.003655336`.

The weird thing is when I did the following

```
k <- -0.003655336
k ^ (1 / 3)
```

`NaN` was produced again.

Comment: Could you please give a reproducible example? and the values of n and k

Answer (score 3):

You are calculating the cube root of a negative number. Although, as pointed out by @mra68, a real solution exists, the general case of non-integer exponents of negative numbers results in a complex number. Since by default R assumes that you are dealing with real numbers, it produces `NaN`.

Try this:

```
k <- -0.003655336
k <- as.complex(k)
k ^ (1 / 3)
#[1] 0.0770216+0.1334053i
```

The result is not unique in the sense that there are three complex numbers `x` satisfying the condition `x^3=k` (including the case where the imaginary component is zero), but the `NaN` output is consistent with the general case case of non-integer numbers as exponents of negative real numbers. It may be argued that a distinction between rational and non-rational exponents could be useful, but in floating-point calculations this is hardly possible. I would consider the occurrence of `NaN`in the case of non-integer exponents of negative numbers as a useful warning sign.

Comment: Every real number, positive or negative, has one cube root that is real, since 3 is odd. If we are not interested in the other two (non-real) cube roots, it is really not necessary to use complex numbers here. Unfortunately in your solution only one of these non-real cube roots shows up.

Comment: Also each positive real number has three cube roots and only one of them is real. So the fact that there are three cube roots is not really a good reason to give `NaN` as the result for a cube root of a real number, if that number is negative, but not if it is positive. (Unfair, isn't it?) But it seems to be implemented that way. The reason might be that R first computes 1/3 and then treats it like any other real number `a`. The fact that it is the reciprocal of an odd natural number is no longer visible. If the number `x` in `x^a` is positive this doesn't matter, if it's negative it does,

Comment: @mra68 I agree with what you say; but I think that this is really an exceptional situation in the sense that the denominator in the exponent is an integer. R cannot really know this if it converts (as I assume) 1/3 into a floating point number. Take for instance `x=(-k)^0.3333333332` with `k` as a positive real number, and you won't have any real solution for `x`. In general I'd use great caution whenever non-integer exponents are applied to negative numbers, and I think it is a good warning sign that R gives `NaN` in such cases.

Comment: @mra68 Thanks for your input; I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The 5-th root of a negative number is still possible. Also my pocket calculator does it. Since (-1)^5=-1, you can do it this way:

```
> tau <- 0.25

> a <- (4.5 * dnorm(qnorm(tau)) ^ 4 * qnorm(tau) / (2 * (qnorm(tau) ^ 2 + 1)) ^ 2)

> sign(a)*abs(a)^ (1/5)
[1] -0.3255258
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your question. 
And you gave yourself the answer. Is basic math. You can't give a power  of a negative number to a power of a decimal number. It is an indetermination.